# understanding unlogged tables, commits and checkpoints postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have to upsert large number of rows in multiple tables in Postgres 9.6 daily. 6 million rows of 1kb each can be loaded on some of these tables, volume is extremely large and this needs to be done rather quickly.

I have some transformation needs so I cannot use copy directly from source; also, copy doesn't update existing rows. I could use fdw wrapper after transformation, but that will also require SQL. So, I decided to write a java program using producer consumer concurrency pattern with producers reading from files, and consumers writing to postgres with multi row upserts.

I can recreate data from ultimate source, I figure I can skip WAL and use unlogged tables -  make them unlogged before copy and make them logged after copy, I am on v9.6.

I did all this and now want to perform performance tests, before I do that I want to know what a commit and checkpoint of an unlogged table means. I suspect data and index files (I have dropped the index) are going to be written at checkpoint. Here are my questions

1) What happens at commit since commit applies to WAL and there is no data for unlogged tables in WAL? Is commit writing my data and index files to disk; or, its unnecessary operation and data will only be written at checkpoint?

2) Ultimately, what should I be tuning for unlogged tables?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends a lot on `wal_level`. At `wal_level = minimal` the cost of switching to logged is low. At higher levels, it involves basically writing the whole table out into WAL.

Comment: Understood. Thanks !